# What is the exact advantage of using a <span> tag, over a <div> tag?

Tags: html

I'm aware of the general difference but what is the exact purpose/advantage of using a span tag over a div tag?

ie.

```
<p>hello <span>world</span></p>
```

and

```
<p>hello <div>world</div></p>
```

Absolutely no difference in the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the div there legally. It's a block element. Span is inline.

Comment: Are they like that per some specification, though?  Block vs. inline by itself can be manipulated via CSS.  That is, are they different because they're block vs. inline, or are they block vs. inline because they're different for another reason?

Comment: Yes, it's per some specification.

Comment: @Satya: I guess what I'm trying to do here is get people to think about their answers.  Yes, there's a specification.  I think we all know that.  But is there more of a difference in the semantic meaning of these tags beyond their display properties?  For example, a screen reader doesn't care much about block vs. inline, does it?  Talking about only markup and not visual style, what is the actual semantic difference between these markup tags?

Comment: Semantically, yes, there's a difference. A div is a block division of your document, a span is a relatively smaller span of text.

Answer (score 0):

There are different kinds of elements (`block`, `inline`, `table`...).

Example for block elements are: `h1`, `p`, `div`, ...

Examples for inline elements are: `em`, `block`, `span`, ...

An block element can contain inline elements and text. Some block elements can contain also other block elements (like `div`) while others cannot (like `p`). Block elements start a new line in the text flow.

Inline elements can contain other inline elements and text but not block elements. Inline elements do not start a new line in the text flow.

Since `<p>` is an block element which should not contain other block elements you shouldn't use a `<div>` inside. Use the `<span>` here.